# Error when running ASP.NET Web Site of SQL error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Alright so I'm building an ASP.NET web site, currently creating the log in form however I keep getting an error that I am unable to attach a SQL Server file.

I did some research and found I needed to create an `app_data` folder in my directory which I did, and in that folder now there are 3 `.mdf` files (SQL Server primary data files) which I cannot open in SQL Server Management Studio.

Looks like similar problems are solved by fixing a connection to a SQL Server. However, in my web site I don't have a connection to an SQL Server declared so why is there a SQL Server error? Also attaching the function that is being called

```
Protected Sub Login1(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles loginForm.LoggingIn
    Dim bolloginCheck As Boolean
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert(' " & loginForm.UserName.Trim() & " - " & loginForm.Password.Trim() & " ');", True)  'displays localhostsays : called fomrcode-behind directly!
    bolloginCheck = _client.Verify_Login(loginForm.UserName, loginForm.Password)
    If bolloginCheck = True Then
        'set user name Or session variable, adjust to true And authenticated
        Response.Redirect("https://www.google.com")
    Else
        loginForm.FailureText = "Unable to login, please review your login credentials."
    End If
End Sub

    Public Function Verify_Login(strUsername As String, strPassword As String) As Boolean Implements IService.Verify_Login
        Return True
    End Function

<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService
    ''WEBSITE FUNCTIONS''
    <OperationContract()>
    Function Verify_Login(uname As String, pword As String) As Boolean
End Interface
<DataContract()>
Public Class CompositeType
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property BoolValue() As Boolean
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property StringValue() As String
End Class

Public Class Service
    Implements IService
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Function Verify_Login(strUsername As String, strPassword As String) As Boolean Implements IService.Verify_Login
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

Error:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Dewy\Desktop\TestWebSite\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: Do you have a connection string in your Web.Config?  This is probably looking for a DB `_client.Verify_Login(loginForm.UserName, loginForm.Password)`

Comment: @Tyddlywink thank you for responding. I do not see a connection string in my web.config. And _client is a iservice object and verify_login is a functioned declared in those service files, however I have not written any SQL part yet and just returns true for now.

Comment: At what line in your code is it throwing this error?   Are you showing that line of code?  If verify_Login is just an empty function returning true everytime then this code shouldn't be firing that exception.  Something is missing.

Comment: @Tyddlywink I tried debugging some more and found the error comes whenever I try and use a function from the service client I created. I originally thought the problem was accessing front end form data. So it  is in the line `_client.Verify_Login(loginForm.UserName, loginForm.Password)`

Comment: You'll need to share that function if you are wanting help.

Comment: Heres the function, I havent added the SQL or functionality to it, I'm only in early stages and am trying to test connection to the service first , added that code to the original post.

Comment: Show the entire  `_client` class.

Comment: @Tyddlywink added the client class hope it helps. still stuck on this, took a break from it.

Comment: That's the Interface that your class implements.  I want to see the class that implements this Interface.

Comment: @Tyddlywink added it. Think this is what your'e looking for.

Comment: Err...all that does is return true. Somewhere (else) you must have some code which tries to connect to a database.

Comment: Somewhere you are trying to connect to a Database.  To help anymore I'm pretty much going to need to see everything.  If you can arrange that I'll peak at it and see if something jumps out.  But other than that....shrug.

Comment: @Tyddlywink is there a way to send you those files or share them other than to post them on a public forum like this

Comment: Get a copy up in github or similar and send the URL to ilikepiealotmorethananyone@gmail.com.  make sure there isn't any sensitive information like user names password or real contact information in the project when you upload it.